# AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2022 failing on deploy lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, visual-studio-2022, aws-toolkit

I'm trying to update one lambda to the AWS Cloud, but suddenly this error started to appear:

> Error attempting to fix the trust policy for IAM Role...

[image]

Checking the "Trust Relationoships" tab on AWS Web Console, like demanded by the error message, averything looks like ok:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Some idea about how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I use more then one account, some time I change this credentials (I know that is possible to configure profiles).

You can define multiple profiles within the credentials files that live in the `.aws` folder under your user home folder. Information about these files can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/credentials.html

If your credentials are simple access key - secret key pairings, you can use the AWS Toolkit to create new profiles. In Visual Studio, go to the `View` menu and select `AWS Explorer`. From the AWS Explorer, there will be buttons that allow you to add/edit/delete credentials profiles. Using these will allow you to create or modify a profile's access key and secret key. More details about this workflow can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/keys-profiles-credentials.html

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that my credentials are wrong.

The AWS Toolkit uses credentials configured in the terminal and saves it under the folder ".aws" into the user home folder.

How I use more then one account, some time I change this credentials (I know that is possible to configure profiles).